# Смена TextView на EditText для редактирования строки

Tags: android, listview, textview, android-edittext

В ListView имеются элементы со строками. Необходимо при долгом нажатии на элементе listview менять textView на editText для редактирования этой строки.

Вот отрывок с xml элемента Listview:

```
<TextView 
            android:id="@+id/list_title_parent_item"
            style="@style/list_parent_title_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:lines="1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/list_title_edit_parent_item"
            style="@style/list_parent_title_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:lines="1" /> <requestFocus />
```

EditText вначале скрыт. Как уже писал выше - он сменяет TextView при долгом нажатии на элементе ListView. Метод для ListView:

private class ListViewOnLongClickListener implements OnItemLongClickListener {

```
@Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            GroupListAdapter adapter = (GroupListAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
            adapter.setTitleEditable(view);         
            return true;
        }

    }
```

метод SetTitleEditable() в адаптере:

```
public void setTitleEditable(View viewConvert) {
        TextView title = (TextView)viewConvert.findViewById(R.id.list_title_parent_item);
        EditText titleEdit = (EditText)viewConvert.findViewById(R.id.list_title_edit_parent_item);

        if (title.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            title.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        titleEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        titleEdit.requestFocus();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(titleEdit, 0);    
        }
        else {
            title.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            titleEdit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

В итоге - первое долгое нажатие происходит успешно и EditText сменяет TextView. Но вот уже такое же нажатие на появившемся EditText - приводит к вылету и исключению NullPointerEx :

```
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at ru.akostyukewicz.easytodo.adapters.GroupListAdapter.setTitleEditable(GroupListAdapter.java:92)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at ru.akostyukewicz.easytodo.activities.GroupList$ListViewOnLongClickListener.onItemLongClick(GroupList.java:111)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at android.widget.AbsListView.showContextMenuForChild(AbsListView.java:3177)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at android.view.ViewGroup.showContextMenuForChild(ViewGroup.java:617)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at android.view.View.showContextMenu(View.java:4289)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at android.view.View.performLongClick(View.java:4250)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8252)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:17246)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
04-15 15:28:54.150: E/AndroidRuntime(15511):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

В принципе не в этом вся суть. Наверное многие видели такую фишку в приложениях для редактирования, которую я хочу реализовать. Как мне теперь обрабатывать потерю фокуса с EditText'а и после этого сразу менять обратно на TextView с уже новым значением?

Comment: Стоп, у Вас ошибка NullPointerException. Сделайте debug в методе onItemLongClick

Comment: я сейчас исправил это. Вопрос остаётся насчёт потери фокуса. Дело в том что если ставлю onFocusChange для EditText'а, то наблюдаю что этот фокус меняется по нескольку раз после нажатия. Как в таком случае быть?